# Add missing values in vector

Tags: r

I have the following `vector <-c ("1.2", "1.11", "5.3", "5.5")` and I want to complete it so that the output is

```
1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5
```

You see, `1.11` is higher than, for example, `1.5` because it is the 11th `element of 1.`

It is basically grouped and sorted by the number before the floating point and then sorted by the number after the floating point with added values.
Always start with a `.1`

I tried using `seq`, but of course it does not work since the digits `1.3` would be bigger than `1.11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(tstrsplit(x, "\\."))[, .(V2 = seq_len(max(as.integer(V2)))), by = V1
                                   ][, paste(V1, V2, sep = ".")]
# [1] "1.1"  "1.2"  "1.3"  "1.4"  "1.5"  "1.6"  "1.7"  "1.8"  "1.9"  "1.10" "1.11" "5.1"  "5.2"  "5.3"  "5.4"  "5.5"
```

Using pipes:

```
tstrsplit(x, "\\.") |>
  as.data.table() |>
  DT(, .(V2 = seq_len(max(as.integer(V2)))), by = V1) |> 
  DT(, paste(V1, V2, sep = "."))
```

Comment: nice answer with `data.table`. easy to group and genate new sub-sequences, +1!

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution (if you want a vector simply use `unlist`)

```
mapply(
    function(x,y){
      paste0(
        as.numeric(strsplit(x,"\\.")[[1]][1]),
        ".",
        seq(1,as.numeric(strsplit(y,"\\.")[[1]][2]),1)
      )
    },
    vector[seq(1,length(tmp),2)],
    vector[seq(2,length(tmp),2)]
  )

$`1.2`
 [1] "1.1"  "1.2"  "1.3"  "1.4"  "1.5"  "1.6"  "1.7"  "1.8"  "1.9"  "1.10" "1.11"

$`5.3`
[1] "5.1" "5.2" "5.3" "5.4" "5.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here might be one base R code you can use (I used `v` instead of `vector` to avoid colliding with the built-in function `vector`)

```
do.call(
  paste,
  c(rev(
    stack(
      lapply(
        split(
          gsub(".*\\.", "", v),
          gsub("\\..*", "", v)
        ),
        function(x) {
          seq(max(as.integer(x)))
        }
      )
    )
  ),
  sep = "."
  )
)
```

which gives

```
 [1] "1.1"  "1.2"  "1.3"  "1.4"  "1.5"  "1.6"  "1.7"  "1.8"  "1.9"  "1.10"
[11] "1.11" "5.1"  "5.2"  "5.3"  "5.4"  "5.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option that `paste`s `seq`uences in a `by`.

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(vector, '\\.')) |>
  (\(s) by(s, s[, 1], \(z) {
    Reduce(\(x, y) paste(y, x, sep='.'), z[1], seq(max(as.numeric(z[, 2]))))
    }))() |>
  unlist() |> unname()
# [1] "1.1"  "1.2"  "1.3"  "1.4"  "1.5"  "1.6"  "1.7"  "1.8"  "1.9"  "1.10" "1.11"
# [12] "5.1"  "5.2"  "5.3"  "5.4"  "5.5"
```